# What hex colors are produced by dyeing signs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

## Story

There are two ways to colour signs in Minecraft: Java Edition:

1. Colour the sign by holding a dye in your hand, then right-click on the sign.
2. Use cheats to modify a sign's raw JSON text to something like:

   ```
   {"text":"Green means go!","color":"green"}
   ```

## Problem

It seems like the dye colours don't seem to match any of the values used by [raw JSON text](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format) or [formatting codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes). Examine the images below:

[image][image]
[image][image][image][image][image]

It doesn't seem like any of the dyes match up to an actual JSON text colour, instead, they all seem to be colours of their own. I would like to match them up to actual hexadecimal numbers so I can have them for a reference. Surprisingly, the Minecraft Wiki does not state the actual colour values.

## Core question

**What are the exact hex code colours produced by dyeing a sign?** <sup>(yes, it's dyeing, not dying)</sup>

- **P.S:** It seems like the JSON colour `dark_gray` and Light Gray Dye *may* produce the same colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late to this, but by editing the `rendertype_text` shader to remove the shading, I got a collection of all the dye hex codes.

| Dye | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| Red Dye | `#660000` |
| Orange Dye | `#66290C` |
| Yellow Dye | `#666600` |
| Lime Dye | `#4C6600` |
| Green Dye | `#006600` |
| Light Blue Dye | `#3D4C52` |
| Cyan Dye | `#006666` |
| Blue Dye | `#000066` |
| Pink Dye | `#662A48` |
| Purple Dye | `#400C60` |
| Magenta Dye | `#660066` |
| White Dye | `#666666` |
| Light Grey Dye | `#545454` |
| Grey Dye | `#333333` |
| Black Dye | `#000000` |

Hopefully this will still be useful to someone 1 and a half years later…

Comment: Thank you for this, and there's absolutely no problem that it's been more than a year. Answers are always appreciated, and I'm glad to have found out the right answer after so long. As for your answer, since it maps item names to colour codes, the best format for that would be a table, so I updated your answer with those, as well as using code formatting for the appropriate parts (you can never have too much!) Thank you again!

Comment: Nice, that looks much better. Also glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access the code whatsoever for hex codes of each color, then try using an editing software, then try to get the colors of each sign via screenshots.

My results:

- Red: (#650000), (101, 0, 0)
- Orange: (#65290C), (101, 41, 12)
- Yellow Dye: (#656500), (101, 101, 0)
- Lime Dye: (#4B6500), (75, 101, 0)
- Green Dye: (#006500), (0, 101, 0)
- Light Blue Dye: (#3C4B51), (60, 75, 81)
- Cyan Dye: (#006565), (0, 101, 101)
- Blue Dye: (#000065), (0, 0, 101)
- Pink Dye: (#652A47), (101, 42, 71)
- Purple Dye: (#3F0C5F), (63, 12, 95)
- Magenta Dye: (#650065), (101, 0, 101)
- White Dye: (#656565), (101, 101, 101)
- Light Gray Dye: (#535353), (83, 83, 83)
- Gray Dye: (#323232), (50, 50, 50)
- Black Dye: (#000000), (0, 0, 0)

> Done with MS Paint.

**Bonus!** Here are the JSON results from your signs according to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes):

- Red: (#FF5555), (255, 85, 85)
- Dark Red: (#AA0000), (170, 0, 0)
- Gold: (#FFAA00), (255, 170, 0)
- Yellow: (#FFFF55), (255, 255, 85)
- Dark Green: (#00AA00), (0, 170, 0)
- Green: (#55FF55), (85, 255, 85)
- Dark Blue: (#0000AA), (0, 0, 170)
- Blue: (#5555FF), (85, 85, 255)
- Aqua: (#55FFFF), (85, 255, 255)
- Dark Purple: (#AA00AA), (170, 0, 170)
- Light Purple: (#FF55FF), (255, 85, 255)
- White: (#FFFFFF), (255, 255, 255)
- Gray: (#AAAAAA), (170, 170, 170)
- Dark Gray: (#555555), (85, 85, 85)
- Black: (#000000), (0, 0, 0)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that this is *close*, not *exact* because of lighting

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accept an approximation. For example, the JSON colour red is actually documented as `#FF5555`, we can see that the colour you obtained is slightly off. Sorry!

Comment: Okay, I've seen you've changed the JSON colours to be correct, but I'm more concerned about the actual dye colours, which I'm quite sure you can't get the exact colour from in-game screenshots alone.